# Combined sequential dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following data in my table

[image: table data]

on the basis of `shift_id` I want to combined the shift dates.

in short I want the following output :

```
**output format : FromDate To ToDate (Shift_id)**

2012-12-01 To 2012-12-02 (2)

2012-12-03 (1)

2012-12-04 (2)

2012-12-18 To 2012-12-20 (1)

2012-12-21 To 2012-12-22 (2)

2012-12-23 To 2012-12-24 (1)

2012-12-25 To 2012-12-30 (2)
```

I tried couple of things but no luck. any one please help/guide me to solve this.

I wrote this code

```
    while($row_shift = mysql_fetch_object($result_shift)) {
    $new_date = $row_shift->shift_date;
    $new_shift = $row_shift->shift_id;
    if($new_shift !== $old_shift) {
        $shift_name = $new_shift;
        $shift_date_1 =  date('D d M',strtotime($new_date))." (".$shift_name.")";               
    } else {
        $shift_name = $old_shift;
        $shift_date_1 =  date('D d M',strtotime($old_date))." (".$shift_name.")";
        $diff = abs(floor( (strtotime($new_date) - strtotime($old_date)) / 3600 / 24));
        if($diff == 1) {                    
            $to_part = ' To ';
            $shift_date_2 = date('D d M',strtotime($new_date))." (".$shift_name.")";

        } else {
            $to_part = ' To ';
            $shift_date_2 = date('D d M',strtotime($old_date))." (".$shift_name.")";    
        }
    }

    $s_d_2 = $to_part.$shift_date_2;

    $shift_date[] = $shift_date_1.$s_d_2;

    $old_date = $row_shift->shift_date;
    $old_shift = $row_shift->shift_id;

}
echo implode("<br/>", $shift_date);
```

and output of this code is

```
Output : 
Sat 01 Dec (2)
Sat 01 Dec (2) To Sun 02 Dec (2)
Mon 03 Dec (1)Sun 02 Dec (2)
Tue 04 Dec (2)Sun 02 Dec (2)
Tue 18 Dec (1)Sun 02 Dec (2)
Tue 18 Dec (1) To Wed 19 Dec (1)
Wed 19 Dec (1) To Thu 20 Dec (1)
Fri 21 Dec (2)Thu 20 Dec (1)
Fri 21 Dec (2) To Sat 22 Dec (2)
Sun 23 Dec (1)Sat 22 Dec (2)
Sun 23 Dec (1) To Mon 24 Dec (1)
Tue 25 Dec (2)Mon 24 Dec (1)
Tue 25 Dec (2) To Wed 26 Dec (2)
Wed 26 Dec (2) To Thu 27 Dec (2)
Thu 27 Dec (2) To Fri 28 Dec (2)
Fri 28 Dec (2) To Sat 29 Dec (2)
Sat 29 Dec (2) To Sun 30 Dec (2)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should explain where you are facing the problem, and what you have tried

Comment: This is fairly easy using loops. Just grab the dates from the database and iterate them in a for or a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e80a5/17)

```
select min(shift_date) start_data,max(shift_date) end_date,
          min(Shift_id) Shift_id
from
(
select t.*,if(shift_id<>@CurShift,@i:=@i+1,@i) Group_num,
       @CurShift:=shift_id 
from t, (select @CurShift:=0,@i:=0) t1 
order by shift_date
 ) b

group by Group_num
order by Group_num
```

Comment: Hey valex, I am trying to understand your query. Can you please explain?